# Unable to reach home.jsp

Tags: spring, jsp

I have an app. Due to some issues, in my web.xml, I had to change the url pattern from "/" to "*.action", and added a welcome-file-list. This is my web.xml now:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">

    <!-- The definition of the Root Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/root-context.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- Creates the Spring Container shared by all Servlets and Filters -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!-- Processes application requests -->
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
            <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring/appServlet/servlet-context.xml</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
         <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>home.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>appServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

Before I did the change, I was able to reach home.jsp by simply typing localhost:8080/myapp in my browser. What should I type now to reach the home page?

Thank you.

NOTE: Im using Spring.

EDIT:

Forgot my HomeController:

```
@Controller
public class HomeController {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);

    /**
     * Simply selects the home view to render by returning its name.
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/")
    public String home(Locale locale, Model model) {
        logger.info("Welcome home! The client locale is {}.", locale);

        Date date = new Date();
        DateFormat dateFormat = DateFormat.getDateTimeInstance(DateFormat.LONG, DateFormat.LONG, locale);

        String formattedDate = dateFormat.format(date);

        model.addAttribute("serverTime", formattedDate );

        return "home";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your request should ends with ".action" try to sent localhost:8080/myapp/some.action
And change mapping in controller to "/some.action"

Comment: I tried reaching it by typing localhost:8080/myapp/home.action but it does not work

Comment: change mapping in controller to "/some.action"

Comment: Yeah, I forgot to change the controller mapping. Its working now. Thank you.

Comment: Name of your view has nothing to do with request url